# Merge Typescript Record or dictionary-like type with fixed key typings?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to extend the built-in Record (or a { [key:string]: string } interface) where you also define some fixed keys and their types?

Let's say we have this:

```
const otherValues = {
    some: 'some',
    other: 'other',
    values: 'values',
}

const composedDictionary = {
    id: 1,
    ...otherValues
}
```

I want to define an interface for composedDictionary where `id` is typed as `number` (and number only) and everything else as `string`.

I've tried this:

```
interface ExtendedRecord extends Record<string, string> {
    id: number;
}
```

and this:

```
interface MyDictionary {
    [key: string]: string;
    id: number;
}
```

Both fail with:

`Property 'id' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index type 'string'`

Any ideas?

Comment: worth nothing that if you're using `any` rather than `string`, this works, though I don't know why: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMicsACYBcyIArgLYBG0ANMaVBAI63CfkAFKAHscARmoBnMFFABzNqWQBtANYR0UmfIC61OCHSEAvoUKhIsRCgwARYAjDBhIOFHTIiSitTpNo7CRqGlqyIHJ6yNJhCiZAA

Comment: @OliverRadini `any` works because it is intentionally unsound... it essentially turns off type checking.  All types are assignable both to and from `any`, which is useful but logically inconsistent... e.g., assignability should be transitive, so if you can assign type `A` to `B`, and `B` to `C`, then you should be able to assign `A` to `C`.  But replace `B` with `any` and you get nonsense like `string` should be assignable to `number`.

Comment: @Meldon are you interested in a solution where `MyDictionary` is not a concrete type but a generic constraint?  That is, instead of `const foo: MyDictionary = ...` youd do `const asMyDictionary = <T extends MyDictionary<T>>(d: T)=>d` and `const foo = asMyDictionary(...)`

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is not recommended. See the "All members must conform to the string index signature" section [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/index-signatures.html) which says: "As soon as you have a string index signature, all explicit members must also conform to that index signature." Could you instead create a composition of the `Record` class and the `id` property, i.e. `interface ExtendedRecord { props: Record<string, string>, id: number }` ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys!

Comment: @YoniGibbs you're right; I'll try to refactor.

Comment: @jcalz That does sound interesting, just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ideally the index signature should reflect **any** possible indexing operation result. If you access `composedDictionary` with an uncheckable  string key the result might be `number` if that `string` is actually `'id'` (eg: `composedDictionary['id' as string]`, the typings would say this is `string` but at runtime it turns out to be `number`). This is why the type system is fighting you on this, this is an inconsistent type.

You can define your index to be consistent will all properties:

```
interface MyDictionary {
    [key: string]: string | number;
    id: number;
}
```

There is a loophole to the checks typescript does for index and property consistency. That loop hole is intersection types:

```
type MyDictionary  = Record<string, string> & {
  id: number
}


const composedDictionary: MyDictionary = Object.assign({
    id: 1,
}, {
    ...otherValues
});
```

The compiler will still fight you on assignment, and the only way to create such an inconsistent object in the type system is by using `Object.assign`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, considering your mild undertone of disapproval and also taking @YoniGibbs comment into account, I will refactor and try to avoid such inconsistent objects :D

Comment: @Meldon I try not to be too judgmental, there are use cases for this, but best avoided if you can :)

Answer (score 10):

As the other answer said, TypeScript does not support a type in which some properties are *exceptions* to the index signature... and thus there is no way to represent your `MyDictionary` as a consistent concrete type.  The inconsistent-intersection solution (`{[k: string]: string]} & {id: number}`) happens to work on property reads, but is difficult to use with property writes.

---

There was an old [suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7765) to allow "rest" index signatures where you can say that an index signature is supposed to represent all properties *except* for those specified.

There's also a more recent (but possibly shelved) pair of enhancements implementing [negated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) and [arbitrary key types for index signatures](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797), which would [allow you to represent such exception/default index signature properties](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317#issuecomment-487643147) as something like `{ id: number; [k: string & not "id"]: string }`.  But that doesn't compile yet (TS3.5) and may never compile, so this is just a dream for now.

---

So you can't represent `MyDictionary` as a *concrete* type.  You *can*, however, represent it as a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints).  Using it suddenly requires that all your previously concrete functions must become generic functions, and your previously concrete values must become outputs of generic functions.  So it might be too much machinery than it's worth.  Still, let's see how to do it:

```
type MyDictionary<T extends object> = { id: number } & {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends "id" ? number : string
};
```

In this case, `MyDictionary<T>` takes a candidate type `T` and transforms it into a version which matches your desired `MyDictionary` type.  Then we use the following helper function to check if something matches:

```
const asMyDictionary = <T extends MyDictionary<T>>(dict: T) => dict;
```

Notice the self-referencing constraint `T extends MyDictionary<T>`.  So here's your use case, and how it works:

```
const otherValues = {
  some: "some",
  other: "other",
  values: "values"
};

const composedDictionary = asMyDictionary({
  id: 1,
  ...otherValues
}); // okay
```

That compiles with no errors, because the parameter to `asMyDictionary()` is a valid `MyDictionary<T>`.  Now let's see some failures:

```
const invalidDictionary = asMyDictionary({
    id: 1,
    oops: 2 // error! number is not a string
})

const invalidDictionary2 = asMyDictionary({
    some: "some" // error! property id is missing
})

const invalidDictionary3 = asMyDictionary({
    id: "oops", // error! string is not a number
    some: "some" 
})
```

The compiler catches each of those mistakes and tells you where the problem is.

---

So, this is the closest I can get to what you want in as of TS3.5.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAiBLAxsRB7AdgQwE4gB4AVKCAD2AkwBMBnKdAIwCsJUA+KAXigG8pE1AFxRMAVwC2jCLigBfKADI+AKChQA2gGkBmKAGsIIdADMoRALoid5SjXoAiQQ6gB+UZOmyRtYLkSYAOYqcgDcKirIWL5Q2LRwSKgYOPjcUMSkFFR0sAgoaFh4hETs7AAU1PkiRACU3JyVqOGR0cAMwAAWMgBq2AA2YhD0PLxqULToEhAiDhNTDgA0Y+idMjMrXbiLYwBu-YO0M3sDQw4hzVGYMVESYOi0ENSJBSkgaXEJ+clFZaPqgiIAIxLdQAOnBGx6+yGIRqoSgAHoEQx9NgQBFLjEAsdBM9vqkeB88klCvhfmN-sIoMCKQx0GBDlAAEyI5EyXDoXAAQg8UhkAnomBWsXGfgCwTkNQxrV0OKeX1JIBZhPixJePz+6nGk2mUFmOpcSNIuA53KgYA5kFwoAE1AFUAkiFotHFsOlVza2P6uIVrwAzO9VXjFeStbb1vTaItWcbTTzfP4gvahW1sLyvLS5rr9fMoG6IgWgA)