# Constraint error emerged after upgrading Typescript to 3.8.2

Tags: typescript

The following code used to work just fine using Typescript `3.7.4` :

```js
type Page<TName extends string | undefined, TSchema> = {
  __typename?: TName;
  total: number;
  items: Array<TSchema>;
};

type DataListData = { __typename?: "Query" } & Record<
  string,
  Page<string, any>
>;

function dataList<TData extends DataListData>() {
  // ...
}

// And finally calling :

type MyData = { __typename?: "Query" } & {
  biologyArticles: {
    __typename?: "BiologyArticlePage";
    total: number;
    items: Array<{ __typename?: "BiologyArticle"; id: string }>;
  };
};

dataList<MyData>();
```

After upgrading to version `3.8.2`, I get the following error :

```
Type 'MyData' does not satisfy the constraint 'DataListData'.
  Type 'MyData' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, Page<string, any>>'.
    Property '__typename' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type '"Query" | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Page<string, any>'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Page<string, any>'.
```

What is going on ? Thank you.

Comment: What's `BiologyArticleFragment`?  It would be helpful if you could edit this into an [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) so that others can demonstrate the issue for themselves and suggest fixes. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your reply. I can give the definition of that fragment, by why does it matter ? Shouldn't it just satisfy the constraint `any` ? I'm going to try to give a minimal example, will be back soon.

Comment: You don't have to define it; you could remove it from the example if it isn't relevant.  (although maybe that's what you mean by a minimal example)

Comment: @jcalz No error in the playground using 3.8-beta (no way to test 3.8.2 though ?). I updated the first post with a minimal example that you can test using 3.8.2 if you're willing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there *should* be an error, since `MyData`'s `__typename` property would ideally be checked against both sides of the `DataListData` intersection, and it fails to match `Record<string,  Page<string, any>>`.  The minimum example of this issue I can make looks like:

```
type A = { a: "" } & { [k: string]: object };
let a: A;

type X = { a: "", b: {} }
declare const x: X;
a = x; // error, even in TS3.7

type Y = { a: "" } & { b: {} }; // should be the same as Y
declare const y: Y;
a = y; // error in 3.8.2, no error in 3.7.4
```

Notice that `X` and `Y` are essentially the same type, but in TS3.7, `X` is (correctly) considered to be incompatible with `A`, but `Y` is (incorrectly) considered to be compatible with `A`.

---

Anyway, it looks like the first version of TS with this behavior is `3.8.0-dev.20200111` (Yay binary search through different versions of TS )  Examining the commits for around that date, I find the following pull request: [microsoft/TypeScript#35143](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/35143), entitled "Check combined intersection properties against target index signatures", a bug fix for [microsoft/TypeScript#32484](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32484).  The PR has the following description:

> With this PR we check that all constituents of an intersection source type relate to index signatures in the target type. For example:
>
> ```
> declare let s: { a: string } & { b: number };
> declare let t: { [key: string]: string };
> t = s;  // Error
> ```
>
> Previously, no error was reported above.

That's exactly what's going on here, so we've found the answer.

---

As for what you should do to fix it in your code, I'm not sure.  The normal answer I give when people want "index signatures with exceptions" is to [use generics and conditional types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57422677/2887218), but this complicates things.  Or you could make your index signature property contain a union `"Query" | undefined` and `Page<string, any>` so that `MyData` is assignable to it.  Either way I think this is outside the scope of the question so I will stop speculating now.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to TS3.7.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKAiLUC+UAZMlANoDWmAzsAE4CWAdgOYC6mA9gEYBWEAxsHwBuAFAAbCEIywxo0JCgANBCRk4ANFC6YkBPKIAmA8alrR+HRjSgAPTErGpVt4VAD07qBFq0OtLQgANwhGKCYoABUAZQAmADoAdgBaUXlwaABNVRR1XAJiFB1kfTdPKCoACw4AV3FDbWhgSugqVABbaFQqKEyjEzMLKxsQTEynVRAyrx8-WigrcRAKpn5oWIAGTeSNgEZk3d3RKCA)

[Playground link to TS3.8.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKAiLUC+UAZMlANoDWmAzsAE4CWAdgOYC6mA9gEYBWEAxsHwBuAFAAbCEIywxo0JCgANBCRk4ANFC6YkBPKIAmA8alrR+HRjSgAPTErGpVt4VAD07qBFq0OtLQgANwhGKCYoABUAZQAmADoAdgBaUXlwaABNVRR1XAJiFB1kfTdPKCoACw4AV3FDbWhgSugqVABbaFQqKEyjEzMLKxsQTEynVRAyrx8-WigrcRAKpn5oWIAGTeSNgEZk3d3RKCA)

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer. Why can't I use an index signature like `{ [key in Exclude<string, "a">]: object }` ? I'm interested in solution suggestions btw, I need to make this work.

Comment: `Exclude<string, "a">` is just `string`, since `string` is not represented by the compiler as a union of all possible string literals.  You want to follow [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867).  At one point [there was work](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867#issuecomment-547940152) to get something like your suggestion with `Exclude` working, via negated types (like "`not "a"`) and expanded index signature support, but those have stalled.

Comment: Well, thank you. Here is the follow up question if you still have some time : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60421184/create-type-aliases-to-nested-types-indexed-with-conditional-type-constraint