# Create type aliases to nested types indexed with conditional type constraint

Tags: typescript

Sorry for the obscure title, I couldn't find a better way to express my problem. Here is the thing. I want to create a type constraint as restrictive as possible to represent data that can have the following form :

```js
type Data = {
  __typename?: "Query",
  someKeyNotKnownInAdvance: {
    __typename?: "SomeFixedTypename",
    total: number,
    items: [{}, {}, ..., {}]
  }
}
```

Here is what I came up with following [a suggestion by jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57371839/merge-typescript-record-or-dictionary-like-type-with-fixed-key-typings/57422677#57422677) :

```js
type Page = {
  __typename?: string;
  total: number;
  items: Array<any>;
};

type DataConstraint<Data> = { __typename?: "Query" } & {
  [K in keyof Data]: K extends "__typename" ? "Query" | undefined : Page;
};
```

Now, I need to build two type aliases :

- One that corresponds to the exact `Page` type given a `Data` type that satisfies the constraint. For example :

```js
type Users= {
  __typename?: "Query",
  users: {
    __typename?: "UserPage",
    total: number,
    items: User[]
  }
}

type PageOfData<Data extends DataConstraint<Data>> = /*
  What should go here so that PageOfData<Users> is exactly Users["users"] ?
*/
```

- Another that gives the exact item type of `items` given the same `Data`. For example :

```js
type ItemOfData<Data extends DataConstraint<Data>> = /*
  What should go here so that ItemOfData<Users> is exactly User
*/
```

How should I build those ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PageOfData` is essentially the type of every property of `Data` that's *not* `__typename`:

```
type PageOfData<Data extends DataConstraint<Data>> =
  Data[Exclude<keyof Data, '__typename'>];
```

and then `ItemOfData` is just the type of the `items` array:

```
// helper to get the type of an array
type Elem<A extends Array<unknown>> = A extends Array<infer T> ? T : never;

type ItemOfData<Data extends DataConstraint<Data>> = 
    Elem<PageOfData<Data>['items']>;
```

Note though that this only works because your Users type only has two properties, `__typename` and `users`. If it had more properties we wouldn't be able to extract the necessary types because there's nothing in the contract that tells us that `users` specifically is the property we should be referencing.

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna try this out. Is it valid to use `PageOfData<Data>['items'][number]` instead of using `infer` to get the array element type ?